# NetBeans fails to start from either terminal or GUI in Kali Linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, netbeans, java-8

When I installed NetBeans and ran it for the first time, it told me that NetBeans cannot run on the default openJDK on Kali Linux. So I downloaded and installed JDK32bit from Oracle, and since then it has failed to start. However, when I ran it in the terminal I got this stacktrace. So I thought maybe NetBeans 64bit cannot run on 32bit JDK, so I installed 64bit JDK also, but I am still getting the same problems.

```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost.localdomain: localhost.localdomain: System error
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler$2.run(CLIHandler.java:667)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058)
    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost.localdomain: System         error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1500)
    ... 5 more
```

I just discovered the same applies to Eclipse also, it fails to start and this is the log report:

!SESSION 2017-10-02 23:35:37.652 -----------------------------------------------

```
eclipse.buildId=4.7.0.I20170612-0950
java.version=1.8.0_144
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_NG
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-02 23:35:55.129
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    /home/MW/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/781/0/.cp/libswt-pi3-gtk-4757.so: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
no swt-pi3-gtk in java.library.path
/home/MW/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi3-gtk-4757.so: libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Can't load library: /home/MW/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi3-gtk.so

at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:327)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:236)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:58)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:124)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:80)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:140)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:765)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:160)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.createDisplay(IDEApplication.java:181)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)

!ENTRY com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core 4 0 2017-10-02 23:35:55.414
!MESSAGE <null>
!STACK 0
Unexpected token RIGHT SQUARE(]) at position 0.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:257)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.loadUnknownImages(ImageReplacementService.java:91)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.<init>(ImageReplacementService.java:74)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.services.ImageReplacementService.<clinit>(ImageReplacementService.java:38)
    at com.genuitec.eclipse.theming.core.ThemingCorePlugin.stop(ThemingCorePlugin.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:835)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:828)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:947)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1588)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: eclipse includes native components. You cannot mix and match 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Netbeans is complaining because it cannot resolve localhost. Add `localhost.localdomain` to /etc/hosts like `127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain`

Comment: So, I should get eclipseIDE 64bit to compliment 64bit JDK. is that what you mean?

Comment: If you want to use eclipse, yes.

Comment: Please can you explain the steps to resolve the netbeans localhost problem? I am still new to the Linux stuffs
. Thank you.